# Laravel Eloquent: Getting sum of data in nested relations and adding it as a new attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sum, eager-loading

I want to find a single query for a complex problem (and an even more complicated one). Hope someone can help me.

I've an orders table with many products (many to many relationship). You can order products and select a quantity, which is saved in the pivot table.

I know I can get all orders with their products with

```
$query = Order::with(['products'=>function($q){
   $q->select('name', 'price', 'quantity', 'unit')->orderBy('name','asc');
}]);
```

Now what I want to retrieve is an array of objects containing the name of every product only once with the sum of their quantity for all orders.
In this case, the products represent types of meat. So the outcome should look something like this:

```
[{
 name: steak,
 unit: piece,
 totalQuantity: 20 
},
{
 name: bacon,
 unit: kg,
 totalQuantity: 112 
}
]
```

If someone could come up with a solution for this, that would be great!

Somewhat more complicated:

Every order can also have many colli's (packages) which contain many products with a certain amount/quantity.
So orders table -> manyToMany -> collis table -> manyToMany -> products table

I need the same as above, but now with the sum of all quantities of all products in the colli's together with the sum of all quantities of the other products.

Any help is appreciated because I can't find many in the docs about eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$query = Order::with('products'=>function($q){
   $q->select('name', 'price','unit',DB::raw("SUM(quantity) as total_quantity"))->groupBy('name')->orderBy('name','asc');
});
```

i hope it would work for you.

Comment: Then I get "Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'products.price' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;"

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to the first problem:

```
$allProducts = DB::query()
      ->select(['p.id', 'p.name', 'c.name as category_name', DB::raw('sum(op.quantity) as total_product_quantity')])
      ->from('products as p')
      ->join('order_product as op', 'p.id', '=', 'op.product_id')
      ->join('orders as o', 'op.order_id', '=', 'o.id')
      ->join('categories as c', 'p.category_id', '=', 'c.id')
      ->groupBy('p.id');
```

For the second problem, I get exactly the same table as above. Now with all products in all colli's:

```
$allProductsInAllCollis = DB::query()
      ->select(['p.id', 'p.name', 'c.name as category_name', DB::raw('sum(co.quantity * colp.quantity) as total_colli_quantity')])
      ->from('products as p')
      ->join('colli_product as colp', 'p.id', '=', 'colp.product_id')
      ->join('collis as col', 'colp.colli_id', '=', 'col.id')
      ->join('colli_order as co', 'col.id', '=', 'co.colli_id')
      ->join('orders as o', 'co.order_id', '=', 'o.id')
      ->join('categories as c', 'col.category_id', '=', 'c.id')
      ->groupBy('p.id', 'p.name', 'category_name');
```

(No idea why I had to pass 'p.name' and 'category_name' in the groupBy, but got an sql error otherwise.

Now the last thing to do is perform another groupBy to add 'total_product_quantity' of the first table to 'total_colli_quantity' in the second table. How can I do this with 2 queries saved in variables?

Comment: You should edit your above question or send another question, since you got your answer. otherwise, it doesn't matter since people won't answer people's answer, so edit your primary answer or wright a new one. Good Luck.

Comment: True, new question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63442285/laravel-combine-2-queries-into-1