# Laravel: combine 2 queries into 1

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have the following relationships:

'orders' -> manyToMany -> 'products'

and

'orders' -> manyToMany -> 'collis' -> manyToMany products

[image: Image of entity relation diagram]

Don't mind the other tables in the image.

I want to retrieve all products that are ordered and get the total quantity of each product. The result should look something like:

```
[{id: 6, name: "steak", category_name: "beef", total_product_quantity: "2.00"}
{id: 7, name: "bacon", category_name: "pork", total_product_quantity: "1.00"}
{id: 9, name: "chicken filet", category_name: "chicken", total_product_quantity: "1.00"}
```

I get all products without taking the colli's into account with

```
$allProducts = DB::query()
      ->select(['p.id', 'p.name', 'c.name as category_name', DB::raw('sum(op.quantity) as total_product_quantity')])
      ->from('products as p')
      ->join('order_product as op', 'p.id', '=', 'op.product_id')
      ->join('orders as o', 'op.order_id', '=', 'o.id')
      ->join('categories as c', 'p.category_id', '=', 'c.id')
      ->groupBy('p.id');
```

and all products that were present in colli's with

```
$allProductsInAllCollis = DB::query()
      ->select(['p.id', 'p.name', 'c.name as category_name', DB::raw('sum(co.quantity * colp.quantity) as total_product_quantity')])
      ->from('products as p')
      ->join('colli_product as colp', 'p.id', '=', 'colp.product_id')
      ->join('collis as col', 'colp.colli_id', '=', 'col.id')
      ->join('colli_order as co', 'col.id', '=', 'co.colli_id')
      ->join('orders as o', 'co.order_id', '=', 'o.id')
      ->join('categories as c', 'col.category_id', '=', 'c.id')
      ->groupBy('p.id', 'p.name', 'category_name');
```

Both queries return the same table structure (array) as mentioned above. But now I want to add the total_product_quantity from the first table to the second one, and return the merged table. How can I do this?

My knowledge of sql and even the laravel query builder is quite low, so if there are better ways to write the queries (more eloquent maybe?), let me know please!

Answer (score 0):

you can use relationships to get data,
this relationships is hasManyThrough

try this :

in model Order

```
public function products(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Colli::class, Product::class)->withPivot('quantity');

    }
```